# command line arg?

Tags: python, syntax, import, module

This is a module named XYZ.

```
def func(x)
.....
.....


if __name__=="__main__":
    print func(sys.argv[1])
```

Now I have imported this module in another code and want to use the `func`. How can i use it?

```
import XYZ
```

After this, where to give the argument, and syntax on how to call it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will bring the name `func` into your current namespace so you can use it directly without the module prefix:

```
from XYZ import func
func(sys.argv[1])
```

You can also import the module and call the function using its fully qualified name:

```
import XYZ
XYZ.func(sys.argv[1])
```

There are a couple of other options as well, for more details read the definitive article on [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)

Answer (score 4):

```
import XYZ
print XYZ.func(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import XYZ
XYZ.func('blah')
```

or

```
import XYZ
XYZ.func(sys.argv[1])
```